How to create a custom action for list view of a custom object?
I have a custom object A. I know there is a standard button for creating records for list views called New 'A'. But I want the label to be Add 'A'.
I was planning to create a custom action to create a record with the label that I require. But the target object field has only a 'Note' object.
I would like to create a record for the object 'A' itself. Is it possible to create a custom action to create a record for the same object that contains the list view?

One workaround for this is you can create a self lookup relationship with the custom object and you can find the custom object in the Target Object along with the Note object.
I have sObject Custom Filter custom object in my org. I have created the self lookup relationship field in this object and this object is available in the target object option.
See this recording:
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/29795154?key=31b2b6bcbaa7597a039c357e9b24640c

Update:

I have checked about the error and found that we need to select at least one record to perform the action. It is the default behaviour of the quick action. So, I have found another workaround for this.

You can create an custom button for the list view. Follow the below steps:

Goto to Setup.
Click on Object Manager.
Click on Custom Object.
Click on Buttons, Links, and Actions.
Click on the New Button or Link.
Then Enter Lable and Name.
Select Display Type as "List Button" and Behavior as "Display in existing window without sidebar or header".
Select Content Source as "URL".
In the formula editor add this formula.
{!URLFOR('/lightning/o/t561258__sObject_Custom_Filter__c/new?count=1')}
and click on the Save Button.

Then you can add this button to the list view using the List View Button Layout.
Note: t561258__sObject_Custom_Filter__c is my custom object name. You can replace it with your object.


Output:


I tried this approach. But the problem is that on clicking this action, it asks you to select a record first. Meaning the new record will be a child to a record that you will have to select before creating it.

@arjun, Do you have you added the newly created field to the layout of the quick action?

@arjun, I have updated the answer and added a new alternative to this.
